# sudo: apache restarting a service on CentOS

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, permissions, sudo

I need my web app to restart the dansguardian service (on CentOS) so it needs to run '/sbin/service dansguardian restart'
I have a shellscript in /home/topological called apacherestart.sh which does the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
id=`id`
/sbin/service dansguardian restart
r=$?
return $r
```

This runs ok (logger statement in script for testing output to syslog, so I know it's running)
To make it run, I put this in /etc/sudoers:

```
User_Alias      APACHE=www
# Cmnd alias specification
Cmnd_Alias      HTTPRESTART=/home/topological/apacherestart.sh,/sbin/e-smith/db,/etc/rc7.d/S91dansguardian
# Defaults specification
# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL) ALL
APACHE  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: HTTPRESTART
```

So far so good. But the service does not restart. To test this I created a user david, and fudged the uid/gid in /etc/passwd to be the same as www:

```
www:x:102:102:e-smith web server:/home/e-smith:/bin/false
david:x:102:102:David:/home/e-smith/files/users/david:/bin/bash
```

then logged in as david and tried to run the apacherestart.sh. The problem I get is:

```
/etc/rc7.d/S91dansguardian: line 51: /sbin/e-smith/db: Permission denied
```

even though S91dansguardian and db are in the sudoers command list.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That doesn't look like a sudo error message to me -- it looks like a standard permissions message.

What are the permissions on `/sbin/e-smith/db`, and what is its shebang line (and that program's permissions), if it's a script?

Also, how are you calling the script?  Just because it's mentioned in the sudoers list doesn't mean it's going to magically be special -- you actually need to call it via `sudo`.

Comment: permission is -r-xr-xr--  1 root root

Comment: shebang is #!/usr/bin/perl -w

Answer (score 0):

What is the e-smith script? Also, why are you running this all out of a Cmnd_Alias instead of lobbing it together in the apacherestart.sh script?

Comment: Cmd_alias *was* just apacherestart.sh. Stuffed other bits on just to see if that was where I was going wrong. The e-smith script is just called by the script started by service script.

Answer (score 0):

Basing on Joe H. answer:

```
chmod a+rx /sbin/e-smith
chmod o+x /sbin/e-smith/db
```